# init-db.js does not execute and the Mongo container which I run crashes on the first run but is running normally if restarted. "Connection Closed"

Tags: mongodb, docker, flask

I am quite new to Docker so any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to make a Flask API which connects with a MongoDB Docker Container to store some data. The Flask API is also Dockerized.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5001 main:app
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5001"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongorootpass
    volumes:
      - ./init-db.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.js:ro
      - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I am trying to make a root user in the `mongo` section of this file after which according to my research my `init-db.js` file is ran.

Here is my init-db.js

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.auth("root","mongorootpass");
db = db.getSiblingDB("apm");
db.createUser({
    user: "apm",
    pwd: "apmuserpass",
    roles: [{
        role: 'readWrite',
        db: "apm",
    }]
});
db.createCollection("users");
db.createCollection("users-data");
```

In this file I am trying to authenticate with my `root` user and then create a new db named `apm` after which I am trying to create a new user named `apm` with `readWrite` access to newly created db and then creating collections in the new db.

But every time I run my app with `sudo docker-compose up --build` after removing the container of MongoDB which is generated on my first run and persists if I don't delete it, my MongoDB app crashes on the first start but works fine on the second start but none of my `init-db.js` is executed or it seems, if I connect to the database from Mongo Compass with the `root` user I see the default databases and no new db or user is created.

This is the [LOG](https://paste.ee/p/URm3R)

For all these files I have explained my thought process for what I am trying to do with the file but the files could be doing something else as I followed many tutorials and all of them were not completed so all my Docker files are pieced together from several tutorials and I don't understand much of the Docker files.

Any help on this subject is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no clue about Docker, but I think the config  file `/etc/mongod.conf` is not used. You need to specify the config file when starting `mongod` it is not used by default.

Comment: Yup I also thought about it but have no idea on how to start my mongo container with that config file or rather where I have to specify the command? In the docker-compose.yml or where, no idea about it.